# Magento: Creating own Shipping Method with additional attribute

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.4

I created a module that implements a new shipping method to magento. Currently the module works well.

Shipping method is showing up in onepage checkout.

```
class Tigerbytes_Barverkauf_Model_Carrier_Selbstabholung extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract
```

Now I want to extend the functionality. The new shipping module shouldn't be visible in the frontend anymore. Therefore I added a new attribute to my module. (show_frontend)

config.xml

```
<default>
        <carriers>
            <selbstabholung>
                <active>1</active>
                <allowed_methods>selbstabholung</allowed_methods>
                <methods>selbstabholung</methods>
                <sallowspecific>0</sallowspecific>
                <model>Tigerbytes_Barverkauf_Model_Carrier_Selbstabholung</model>
                <name>Selbstabholung</name>
                <title>Selbstabholung</title>
                <specificerrmsg>Zur Zeit ist die Versandmethode nicht verfuegbar</specificerrmsg>
                <handling>0</handling>
                <handling_type>F</handling_type>
                <show_frontend>0</show_frontend>
            </selbstabholung>
        </carriers>

    system.xml
<show_frontend translate="label">
                            <label>zeige im Frontend?</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </show_frontend>
```

The attribute show_frontend is shown in the backend and also saved in core_config_data table.

The big problem now is when getting the shipping methods for the onepage checkout for user selection there is no show_frontend attribute in the object.

I think the object that is used for the shipping method list is

```
Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Rate
```

So what do I have to extend, that the rate object knows about the show_frontend attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annex:

I just want to permit showing the shipping methode in the frontend. In the backend for backend orders i want to show it.

So in the collectRates() methode i implemented the following condition.

```
if(Mage::getDesign()->getArea() === Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_FRONTEND &&
        !Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$this->_code.'/show_frontend')){

        return false;
    }
```

Now its working perfect!

Answer (score 1):

You are doing all insed you module right?

Just do it:

On your collectRates() method you put this code:

```
if(!Mage::getStoreConfig('carrier/selbstabholung/show_frontend'))
    return false;
```

this code should do the job.

Good day.

Comment: Damn, youre rigth! THX. I was thinking to complecated. :-)

Comment: Yes, sometimes magento can be simple too. ;) Pls mark the answer as Right. ~^